# Automatically capitalize first letter of first word in a new sentence in LaTeX

Tags: latex, letter, uppercase, capitalize

I know one of LaTeX's bragging points is that it doesn't have this Microsoftish behavior. Nevertheless, it's sometimes useful.

LaTeX already adds an extra space after you type a (non-backslashed) period, so it should be possible to make it automatically capitalize the following letter as well.

Is there an obvious way to write a macro that does this, or is there a LaTeX package that does it already?

Comment: you want to type you tex files with small letters only? why?

Comment: because often, i'm too lazy to type caps.

Comment: the place to have your laziness indulged is in your text editor, I think.

Comment: i've wondered about that. perhaps i should let emacs take care of this for me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided to solve it in the following way:

Since I always compile the LaTeX code three times before i okular the result (to get pagination and references right), I decided to build the capitalization of sentences into that process.

Thus, I now have a shell script that calls my capitalization script (written in CRM114) first, then pdflatex three times, and then okular. This way, all the stuff happens as the result of a single command.

Comment: The CRM114 script uses a regexp and the linux command 'tr' to turn any lowercase letter preceded by a period (which, in turn, is not preceded by any known abbreviations) and some whitespace into an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 7):

The following code solves the problem.

```
\let\period.
\catcode`\.\active 
\def\uppercasesingleletter#1{\uppercase{#1}}
\def.{\period\afterassignment\periodx\let\next= }
\def \periodx{\ifcat\space\next \next\expandafter\uppercasesingleletter \else\expandafter\next\fi}

First. second.third.  relax.relax. up
```

`\let\period.` save period

`\catcode\.\active` make all periods to be active symbol (like macro).

`\def\uppercasesingleletter#1{\uppercase{#1}}` defines macro `\uppercasesingleletter` to make automatically capitalize the following letter.

`\def.{\period\afterassignment\periodx\let\next= }` writes saved period and checkes the next symbol.

`\def \periodx{\ifcat\space\next \next\expandafter\uppercasesingleletter \else\expandafter\next\fi}` If the next letter is a space then `\uppercasesingleletter` is inserted.

Comment: that produced the following error:

! Undefined control sequence.
.->\period
           \afterassignment \periodx \let \next =
l.18 \parskip=0.
                5\baselineskip \advance\parskip by 0pt plus 2pt
?

Comment: You're missing a `\let\period=.` before the catcode, I think.  This kind of token munging will work only if you're well-behaved about how you use periods: `{\em first.} second` doesn't work so well.  +1 ingenious, though.

Comment: @Charles. Right. I Inserted it.

Comment: i just can't get the line \catcode`\.\active to work. it produces 'undefined control sequence'.

Comment: @Tom: \active is a chardef in Plain Tex for catcode 13, and is maybe not defined in Latex.  Try running this using tex/pdftex, or using \catcode`\.=13 instead.

Answer (score 4):

ages ago there was discussion of this idea on comp.text.tex, and the general conclusion was you can't do it satisfactorily.  satisfactory, in my book, involves not making characters active, but i can't see how that could work at all.

personally, i would want to make space active, and have it then look at \spacefactor and \MakeUppercase the following character if the factor is 3000.

something like

```
\catcode\ \active % latex already has a saved space character -- \space
\def {\ifhmode% \spacefactor is invalid
% (or something) in vertical mode
\ifnum\spacefactor<3000\else% note: with space active,
% even cs-ended lines need %-termination
\expandafter\gobbleandupper\fi}%
\def\gobbleandupper#1{\def\tempa{#1}\def\tempb{ }%
\ifx\tempa\tempb% can''t indent the code, either :-(
% here, we have another space
\expandafter\gobbleandupper% try again
\else\space% insert a "real" space to soak up the
% space factor
\expandafter\MakeUppercase\fi}%
```

this doesn't really do the job -- there are enough loose ends to knit a fairisle jumper.  for example, given that we can't rely on \everypar in latex, how do you uppercase the first letter of a paragraph?

no ... however much it hurts (which is why i avoid unnecessary key operations) we need to type latex "properly" :-(